# EditText + Button onClick when the user press enter

Tags: java, android, xml

I have the following structure in my main layout:

```
 LinearLayout
      EditText
      EditText
      Checkbox
      Button
```

I'd like that "enter" key at the second `EditText` to cast a `onClick` event at the button. How can I do it? Is possible to do it with only changing the xml?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You can use this

```
((EditText)findViewById(R.id.edittext)).setOnEditorActionListener(
    new EditText.OnEditorActionListener() {
  @Override
  public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
      if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) {
          mButton.performClick(); 
          return true;
      }
      return false;
   }
});
```

Comment: Shouldn't mButton.onClick(mButton) be mButton.performClick(); ?

Answer (score 1):

You can set the behavior for clicking the button in XML. 
Make a method with the behavior you want to have happen when the button is clicked. Then, call it for the button by using [android:onClick](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#onClick)

For the EditText, I believe you can't do it in XML and have to do it as in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7258679/edittext-button-onclick-when-the-user-press-enter/7258784#7258784) from user7777777777.